# Identify coupled rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Have

```
import pandas as pd

df_in = pd.DataFrame({
    'key' : ['000', '001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '006'], 
    'code' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A'],
    'value' : [5, -2, 5, 2, 8, -5, -5]
})
```

### Want

I need to create a 4th column, based on the logic provided below.

- Find the **first occurrence of a matching code and opposite value**, return the `key` of the corresponding value for each row in the dataset.
- EDIT: **Each row is coupled with zero or one other row, but never more than one**.
- EDIT: Numbers can also be zero, and the same rules above apply.

The goal of this script is to pair financial transactions, such that the "key" of one transaction is the "coupled key" of it's corresponding transaction.

In addition, the actual dataset is roughly `150,000 x 22`, so a **scalable** solution is essential.

### Expected Output and Explanation

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame({
    'key' : ['000', '001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '006'], 
    'code' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A'],
    'value' : [5, -2, 5, 2, 8, -5, -5],
    'coupled key' : ['005', '003', '006', '001', 'none', '000', '002']
})
```

- Transaction `000` is coupled with `005`. The first row searches for the first position that contains code "A" and value -5. This returns '005' for the "coupled key" amount, as that is the "key" of the first row which matches the aforementioned condition.
- Transaction `002` is coupled with `006` instead of `000`, because `000` is already paired with `005`.

I have searched unsuccessfully for solutions along the lines of `pd.groupby()`, `pd.groupby().nth()`, mask functions, etc..

Comment: Yes, they can be zero. Edited the dataset.

Comment: Since we're trying to speed up the code, can you post a working solution which isn't fast enough, which we can benchmark our solutions against? It seems like a groupby solution would be plenty fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Completely rewritten because the OP revised the logic.

## Key

1. Assign the running number `no` by `.groupby("value").cumcount()`
2. Left join on `[code, value, no]` against `[code, -value, no]`.
3. For those `value=0`, left join on `[code, int(no/2), no%2]` against `[code, int(no/2), 1 - no%2]` to avoid matching themselves.

Solution cheaper than `groupby` such as `np.searchsorted` is no longer possible because the matching logic is now recursive (i.e. depends on whether there are previous matches for the same `(code, value)` or not).

## Code

I appended 3 zeros to your data to showcase the ability to deal with cases of `value=0`.

```
import pandas as pd

df_in = pd.DataFrame({
    'key': [f'00{i}' for i in range(10)],
    'code': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'X', 'X', 'X'],
    'value': [5, -2, 5, 2, 8, -5, -5, 0, 0, 0]})

# 1. match records with nonzero values
df_in["minus_value"] = -df_in["value"]
df_in["no"] = df_in.groupby(["code", "value"]).cumcount()
df_in = df_in.merge(
    df_in[["key", "no", "code", "minus_value"]], how="left",
    left_on=["code", "value", "no"], right_on=["code", "minus_value", "no"], suffixes=("", "_y"))

# 2. match records with values=zero
mask0 = (df_in["value"] == 0)
df_0 = df_in.loc[mask0, ["key", "code", "value", "no"]].copy()
df_0["no_d2"] = df_0["no"].values >> 1  # divided by 2 and round down
df_0["no_m2"] = df_0["no"].values % 2  # mod 2
df_0["no_m2c"] = 1 - df_0["no_m2"]  # complement of mod 2

key_zeros = df_0.merge(
    df_0[["key", "code", "no_d2", "no_m2c"]], how="left",
    left_on=["code", "no_d2", "no_m2"], right_on=["code", "no_d2", "no_m2c"], suffixes=("_x", ""))["key"]

# put zeros back
df_in.loc[mask0, "key_y"] = key_zeros.values

df_in.rename(columns={"key_y": "coupled key"}, inplace=True)
df_in["coupled key"].fillna('none', inplace=True)
```

## Result

```
print(df_in[["key", "code", "value", "coupled key"]])

   key code  value  coupled key
0  000    A      5          005
1  001    B     -2          003
2  002    A      5          006
3  003    B      2          001
4  004    C      8         none
5  005    A     -5          000
6  006    A     -5          002
7  007    X      0          008
8  008    X      0          007
9  009    X      0         none
```

Comment: I read your comment above and now understand the ambiguity. That's my fault, and I apologize. I edited the post for clarity. I appreciate your response regardless!

Comment: Hi, I have updated the solution in response of your post edit. Please check it out. No need to apologize because IMO it is quite normal to be missing something when asking a puzzling question. We answerers should more or less expect this. Just pay serious attention to the comments and update promptly.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

Created two new columns to help identify the couple:

```
df_in['Key_Value'] = df_in['code'] + df_in['value'].apply(str)
df_in['Key_minus_Value'] = df_in['code'] + (df_in['value']*(-1)).apply(str)
df_in

    key     code  value Key_Value   Key_minus_Value
0   000     A      5    A5          A-5
1   001     B     -2    B-2         B2
2   002     A      5    A5          A-5
3   003     B      2    B2          B-2
4   004     C      8    C8          C-8
5   005     A     -5    A-5         A5
6   006     A     -5    A-5         A5
```

Then I ran the following loop:

```
for kv in df_in['Key_Value']:
    if len(df_in.loc[df_in['Key_minus_Value'] == kv]) > 0:
        df_in.loc[df_in['Key_Value'] == kv, 'coupled key'] = df_in.loc[df_in['Key_minus_Value'] == kv, 'key'].reset_index().iloc[0,1]
    else:
        df_in.loc[df_in['Key_Value'] == kv, 'coupled key'] = 'none'
```

Removing the other columns and printing the dataframe:

```
df_in.drop(columns = ['Key_Value', 'Key_minus_Value'], inplace = True)
df_in

    key  code   value   coupled key
0   000  A      5       005
1   001  B     -2       003
2   002  A      5       005
3   003  B      2       001
4   004  C      8       none
5   005  A     -5       000
6   006  A     -5       000
```

Just one note: when there is more than one eligible pair, this code chooses the first in the index order